# Loop through JSON Data?

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to get a simple page to pull data from SQL Server via a MVC controller using Json.Net

(Sorry for the dirty code - my day job is a SQL Server Dev\DBA.)

Controller:

```
dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
string strjson = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);
return Json(strjson,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Index.cshtml:

```
$.getJSON("/Test/MikeTest", {}, 
        function (myData) {
            alert(myData);
            $.each(myData,function(key,data) {
            alert(key + ":" + data);
        })
```

returned JSON:

```
[{"DateTime":"2013-12-02T12:40:57.387","message":"simple test"}]
```

When I loop through the JSON data each iteration returns a single character rather than     key/name pairs.

Presumably I'm doing something daft & not returning/typing the data correctly - any simple pointers much apprecaited!

Comment: what alert is it showing?

Comment: You may prefer using `console.log`instead of `alert` to debug objects.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Loop Through JSON Data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8134356/loop-through-json-data)

Comment: I dont know why r u using .each when u r returning single string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response from $.getJSON probably is a string, try using "JSON.parse" to make the response an actual object.

Something like:

```
$.getJSON("/Test/MikeTest", {}, 
    function (myData) {
        alert(myData);
        myDataObj = JSON.parse(myData);
        $.each(myDataObj,function(key,data) {
           alert(key + ":" + data);
        })
 });
```

Comment: Thanks! that was what I was missing - I ended up with: 
    alert(key + ":" + data.message);